# Error : "Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" with function randrange()

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm currently coding a discord bot, and I have a command that sends the URL of a random anime using a MyAnimeList api. Here is my code :

```
@client.command()
async def anime(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Récupération d'un anime...")
    anime = 0
    while anime == 0:
        async with ctx.typing():
            try:
                ref = randrange(1, 40500)
                anime = Anime(ref)
                await ctx.send(anime)
            except ValueError as err:
                if str(err) == 'No such id on MyAnimeList':
                    pass
                else:
                    pass
```

I'm using a while loop to retry if the api returns a 404 error (because not every single anime id is used on myanimelist.net)
The error i'm getting is :

```
Ignoring exception in command anime:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "bot.py", line 46, in anime
anime = Anime(ref)
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mal/anime.py", line 8, in __init__
super().__init__(mal_id, "anime", timeout)
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mal/mal.py", line 15, in __init__
title = self._page.find("meta", property="og:title")["content"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 797, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 92, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I think that the problem comes from the fonction randrange(). When i was looking for a solution, every single person with the same issue had a code that was involving lists, but I don't have any in my code...
I'm using Python 3.7.6.
The problem probably comes from the mal-api library itself...

Comment: "subscriptable" - do you have anything similar to `a[0]` or `b[1]` in your code?

Comment: No, I don't use any list in my code.

Comment: The error says the problem is in `anime = Anime(ref)`.  Where is that class coming from?

Comment: `title = self._page.find("meta", property="og:title")["content"]` is the problematic line. `self._page.find("meta", property="og:title")` is returning `None`

Comment: I have found the files of the libraries, but i'm not skilled enough to understand where is the problem...
And even if I could, i wouldn't know how to apply the modifications on my VPS, i don't have root access...

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into rate limiting or something else that is interfering with the web pages you're getting back.  You could try writing a wrapper class around `Anime` to look at the `_page` attribute to see what the problem is:

```
class MyAnime(Anime):
    def __init__(self, ref):
        try:
            super().__init__(ref)
        except:
            print(self._page)
            print(self._page.find("meta"))
            print(self._page.find("meta", property="og:title"))
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, should I add this class to my code or should I run it into a separate file ?

Comment: @LouisD You would add this to your code and use it in the place of `Anime`.  This won't fix your problem, but will allow you to inspect whats causing it.

Comment: The codes return what looks like a 403 error : 
```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
None
None 
```
It was already happening when I was using another VPS, maybe MyAnimeList.net has banned some VPS hosts ? It's weird...